# HTML entities in select lists Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

So I have a select list that's bound to some data:

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected">-- Please select your company --</option>
    <!-- ko foreach: dealerList -->
        <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: name}, foreach: dealers">
            <option data-bind="text: name, option: $data"></option>
        </optgroup>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

However, some of the data (which is being provided by an API) contains HTML entities. Example, the data that gets supplied to the optgroup's label. `&amp;` is rendering as `&amp;`

How can I render these correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I know is using [the `html` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html) (which is like the `text` binding, but it renders html, including entities, as is), but *be ware of the security implications* as well as the fact that most actual *html* isn't valid inside `option` elements.

Here's proof:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  dealerList: [
    {
      name: 'group 1',
      dealers: [
        { name: 'Mark &amp; Sons' }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option selected="selected">-- Please select your company --</option>
    <!-- ko foreach: dealerList -->
        <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: name}, foreach: dealers">
            <option data-bind="html: name, option: $data"></option>
        </optgroup>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

If you cannot trust the data you'd need [a custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) with features somewhere in between `text` and `html`, that only renders entities but not other stuff.